# Possible to write and access temporary file from within MyBinder Python environment?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I need to write an STL file and then parse it within a single script, all within a mybinder.org instance of a share-able python notebook. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out for myself, all that needs to be done.
Possibly terrible practice but functional.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd() # gets directory of docker environment
sys.path.append(cwd)

testfile = cwd + '/testfile.txt'
with open(testfile, 'w') as tf:
    tf.write('Hello World')

with open(testfile, 'r') as tf2:
    print(tf2.read())
```